# RayCasting на python

Tags: python, математика, pygame, 3d

Очень хочу создать 3d игру на пайтон (библиотека pygame). В этом видео:Сделал 3D Игру на Python без движка [#1] | Ray Casting | Pygame , для определения позиции конечной точки луча выпускаемого игроком используется формула: toX, toY = ray_size * cos(player.angle) + player.x, ray_size * sin(player.angle) + player.y

Где player.x (y) - позиция игрока по x (y), player.angle - угол поворота персонажа (в радианах),  ray_size - ширина экрана

И я не понимаю эту формулу, хотя знаю и геометрию и алгебру до 9 класса. Буду очень благодарен за помощь

Comment: toX, toY = ray_size * cos(player.angle) + player.x, ray_size * sin(player.angle) + player.y. Там + а не *

Comment: Видео посмотри. Я вот ради тебя посмотрел, исправил, а ты отменил правку.

Comment: Извини, сильно в экран не вглядывался

Answer (score 0):

По видео он вроде берет ширину как примерно максимальную длину луча. Дальше зная гипотенузу находит катеты и прибавляет к текущей позиции. Эта точка может находиться за пределами экрана. По сути он просто берет отрезок с длиной ray_size, с началом в player.x, player.y, и углом player.angle, и находит его второй конец, и потом строит отрезок от 1 точки до 2.

Всегда рад помочь с RayCasting-ом потому что у меня есть его самописный движок и PythonNumbaNumpyPygame и в С++/SFML

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое, что именно это за гипотенуза, и откуда он ее знает? Тогда сам луч является катетом? Можете пожалуйста привести более подробное объяснение

Comment: Катеты - это позиции по x и y

Comment: Спасибо большое, все понял